# How to determine whether a node_tree is a material or a node group?

Tags: python, scripting

I'd like to know whether a given `node_tree` is either a material or node group as dynamically as possible. The following function works somehow but I don't want to specify the any additional argument for a fundamental reason:

```
def my_function(node_tree):
    #Incomplete example:
    #if node_tree is from material:
        print("It is a node_tree of a material")
    #elif node_tree is node_groups:
        print("It is a node_tree of a node_groups")

# Use case 1:
mat = C.object.active_material
my_function(mat.node_tree) # Returns a node_tree

# Use case 2:
group = D.node_groups["My Groups"] # Returns a node_tree
my_function(groups)
```

`node_tree.id_data` returns a `node_tree` in all my tests so I guess you can use something like `isinstance()` in conjunction with `id_data`? Is there any way to test the actual type like `isinstance(node_tree, bpy.types.???)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How it represents itself.**

In as much as it aint pretty have had to rely on this before, may be for same can't remember.  Noticed in console that the representation  "knows". (*echoing in the console uses `repr(ob)` printing uses `str(ob)`*)

```
>>> D.materials['Material'].node_tree
bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree

>>> D.node_groups['Foo']
bpy.data.node_groups['Foo']
```

as a string is also of little use

```
>>> print(D.materials['Material'].node_tree)
<bpy_struct, ShaderNodeTree("Shader Nodetree") at 0x7f6bd0a86e08>
```

whereas looking at types *et al* kept coming up as same.  Hence can use this in your method

```
>>> def from_material(nodetree):
...     return repr(nodetree).startswith("bpy.data.materials")
...     
>>> from_material(D.materials['Material'].node_tree)
True

>>> from_material(D.node_groups['Foo'])
False
```

alternatively `endswith("node_tree")` is possibly a quicker option.

**Extra,**

> Nice solution. But so how can I get that material into a variable in
> this function?

Once we know it's a material, can slice off ".node_tree" and evaluate it.

```
>>> repr(D.materials['Material'].node_tree)[:-10]
"bpy.data.materials['Material']"

>>> eval(repr(D.materials['Material'].node_tree)[:-10])
bpy.data.materials['Material']
```

Similarly could slice "bpy.data.materials['" from the start and "'].node_tree" from the end to just keep the name.

```
>>> matname = repr(D.materials['Material'].node_tree)[20:-12]
>>> matname
'Material'

>>> D.materials.get(matname)
bpy.data.materials['Material']
```

Comment: Nice solution. But so how can I get that material into a variable in this function?

Comment: Speaking of your very useful "Extra", I wonder why there isn't a simple API similar to id_data that would make things a lot easier. But maybe my approach is wrong and that's why there is no API by the way

Comment: This is one where the assumption that `mat.node_tree.id_data is mat`  isn't so. Possibly since a nodetree is an ID object if in `D.node_groups`